# Pycharm: not indexing shared library (.so) file

Tags: python, pycharm

I have project with structure:

```
./tests
./tests/test_python_ton.py
./__init__.py
./libs
./libs/.gitkeep
./libs/python_ton.cpython-39-darwin.so
./main.py
```

In `test_python_ton.py` file I'm import my pre-built `so` file:

`from tonpy.libs.python_ton import *`

But pycharm failed to index `so` file and mark import as error.
If I run my program it works completly right.

How to force Pycharm to index my `so` file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is a known issue  - [PY-59141](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-59141) - Vote for the issue using the thumbs-up button on the right of the issue summary.